# Firebase Cloud Messaging via Cloud Functions via Http requests

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to implement a messaging procedure for my android application using firebase cloud messaging, i run into some constraints since i do not have any server whatsoever and do not plan to have one of any sort.

What i am intending to do :
- create all needed http requests forms using okhttp. 
- send desired http request to my cloud functions
- these functions will get neede data from firestore and respond to requests while actually sending cloud messages to topics.

This is the only approach i figured out to implement my own sort of REST API since i could not use Admin SDK in my android client applications and do not have any processing server.

Is there any examples, tutorials doing the same ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed don't need to have a server for implementing your Functional Requirements. You can very well use Cloud Functions (a serveless solution) as you have mentioned in you question.

When you want to send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification, you could:

1. Write the content of the notification in a new Firestore document (into a specific documents collection). Here the advantage over implementing an HTTP Cloud Function to send the data is that you keep an history of the requests and it is a little bit easier to code since you would use the Android SDK for Firestore.
2. Set up a Cloud Function that is triggered when a new document is created in this collection and that sent the notifications.

There is an official sample Cloud Function that exactly does that, see https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/fcm-notifications. The code for the function is at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js.

In your case you would trigger the Cloud Function as follows:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notificationsRequests/{requestUid}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {})
```

see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

---

Note that you will find quite a lot of questions & answers on SO that cover this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firestore+send+notifications

Comment: Actually i already browsed many examples for that exact use case, i do not plan to keep a history for that, what i did for now : having a document brodcasts/public wich is updated each time with the new notification i send and a cloud function triggered onUpdate. I think i will stick with this implementation but working with http request will eventually save me from writing all users broadcasts to firestore : user send his broadcast via http and cloud function dispatch it to desired topic subscribers

Answer (score 1):

After some research, i found out that firebase provide exactly what i was looking for named callable functions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

In this way one can exchange notifications without actually transiting by any databases. Hope this can help someone.